# Showing invalid_scope when adding profile or request

Tags: python, api, oauth, sdk, uber-api

I am trying to access `Uber API` for requesting rides and I am trying to access appropriate scope like

- profile
- request_rides
- request

And I successfully got the token, clientid, clientsecret, access_token and Then I tried to access profile by calling

```
from uber_rides.auth import AuthorizationCodeGrant 

auth_flow = AuthorizationCodeGrant(
    <CLIENT_ID>,
    <SCOPES>,
    <CLIENT_SECRET>,
    <REDIRECT_URI>
)
auth_url = auth_flow.get_authorization_url()

session = auth_flow.get_session(redirect_url)
client = UberRidesClient(session, sandbox_mode=True)
credentials = session.oauth2credential
```

Above commands didn't raise any errors but when I execute

```
response = client.get_user_profile()
```

then I showed

> uber_rides.errors.ClientError: 401: This endpoint requires at least one of the following scopes: profile, eats.pos_provisioning, profile.internal_uuid

And When I append profile in below <SCOPES> in browser then It showed `invalid_scope` . I have no idea why it is showing this error every time I call the url to get the session.

In `https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/token?clientid=` POST request, it is showing only `"scope": "offline_access"` in scope.

So How can I get the access of profile and request_rides scope ?

Any help would be much Appreciated.